# Change the kerberos ticket cache location

Tags: windows, hive, odbc, kerberos

I have a trouble with Kerberos on Windows 7.

**What I have:**

- I am on Windows 7
- Under system32, I have klist (from MS Corp) but I don't have kinit
- I have klist and kinit from jdk8 but not included in the PATH environment variable
- I have an ODBC datasource on top of a the Hortonworks 32-bits ODBC driver 2.01, and that datasources relies on kerberos authentication

**What I observe, when my current dir is jdk8/bin:**

- kinit enables to create a ticket and I get: New ticket is stored in cache file C:\Users[login]\krb5cc_[login]
- klist correctly detects all the tickets in that cache

**What I observe, when my current dir is NOT jdk8/bin:**

- klist (system32's) doesn't read from the cache file above

**What I want to do:**

- Somewhat: Tell the ODBC driver to read the Java's Krb cache instead of the system's Krb cache (furthermore, where is it located ???)

**What I have already tried:**

- Adding an environment variable KRB5CCNAME that point to the cache file but that didn't it.

Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Windows does *not* cache the tickets used by the Windows session in a *file* -- and the Windows `klist` is based on SSPI, it does *not* follow the GSSAPI standards like Java does. Check your ODBC driver to see if it supports GSSAPI *(e.g. with Cloudera driver, do not enable "SSPI only" check-box)*

Comment: FYI, recent versions of MIT Kerberos (GSSAPI) have a Windows version that claims to be able to access the Microsoft cache, nicknamed MSLSA https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-latest/doc/basic/ccache_def.html >> but I'm not sure Java supports that...

Comment: Thank You Samson Scharfrichter. So Windows uses SSPI and no cache file whereas Java uses GSSAPI. Not solved the ODBC problem but got my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hortonworks ODBC driver 2.0 cannot be configured to use GSSAPI. In other words, it cannot use a Kerberos ticket created with kinit.

Comment: No kidding?? That would be a **severe regression**, because I used that feature back in 2015 (with _MIT Kerberos for Windows_ as GSSAPI ticket manager), and the current documentation for the ODBC driver (V2.1.7) has several pages about "Configuring Kerberos Authentication for Windows" .